# Using JavaScript count the number of elements equal to or higher than the index in a loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I'm working on a JavaScript function that can create an authors- H-Index.  H-Index is the highest number of publication an author has written with just as many citations in other articles.  I have

```
let array = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,5,6,6,7,20,20,20]
```

This is the number of citied articles in ascending order

I need to loop the array until the index is more that the count of the items equal to or higher than the index

Such as

```
for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
  count all items that are above i (0's get skipped)
  if there are more than i then loop to next i if not exit with i - 1
  console.log(i)
 }
```

What I'm looking for is 6 with an efficient loop.  Thanks for the help

I've played with map and filtered inside the loop but I can't seem to get the correct syntax

Comment: Why not 1?  Because there are more than 1 items that are equal to or higher than 1.  Everything from 1 to 20.  and thanks for the question

Comment: please add which values are counted. its a bit unclear which values to count.

Comment: if i equals 1 then I need to see if there are more than 1 number equal or higher than 1.  If i equal 2 than I need to make sure that there are at least 2 items equal to or higher  such as 2 and 3.  If i= 3 then I need to check 3, 3 and 5

Comment: I need to keep going until the index is larger than the number of items above or equal to that number.  confusing I know  https://subjectguides.uwaterloo.ca/calculate-academic-footprint/YourHIndex

Comment: How efficient?  Is O(n^2) ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reverse the array or sort descending, and find the index where the index (plus one) is greater than the value.

```js
const
    values = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 20, 20, 20],
    hIndex = [...values].reverse().findIndex((v, i) => v < i + 1);

console.log(hIndex);
```

Approach without reversing. Kodos to [Jonas Wilms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-wilms).

```js
const
    values = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 20, 20, 20],
    length = values.length,
    hIndex = length - values.findIndex((v, i) => v >= length - i);

console.log(hIndex);
```

Comment: This is awesome-- I just tried it with 68 items and it works like a champ.  THANK YOU both.  Reversing or sorting is not a real issue because the numbers are random from a JSON url anyway, so they have to put into an order

Comment: this is the line that would create the items in the array   let hIndex =  data.map(d => d.citation_count).sort(function(a, b){return a-b}); coming from a JSON url web service

Comment: This makes no sense to me.. *until the index is **more** that the **count** of the items equal to or higher than the index*. What does your solution return for array `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 20, 20]` ? Shouldn't the answer still be 6, or did I misunderstand what the OP was asking? I guess I misunderstood since this answer was accepted...

Comment: @shidoro, just follow the link in the comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient way, but it can be done with filter.

First, arrays are declared with square braces `[]`, not curly braces `{}`. So, it would be:

`let array = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,5,6,6,7,20,20,20]`

And the operation you ask for would be:

```
array
   .filter((element, index) => element >= index)
   .length
```

The callback that filter accepts can support 3 arguments:

1. The element
2. The index
3. The array

Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: I'll give it a try-- My bad on the curly braces I've been working with JSON all day and this array is a product of the JSON-- not enough sleep-  Thanks